# save object after installation

Tags: android

I'm developing an app in with all functionalities are done over an object 
this object is constructed after heavy , time consuming data processing. This  heavy processing is needed just once after installation and no more. How can I save this object in background in order not to construct it with each application lunch ? I mean I don't want to do this time consuming data processing each time user run the application

Comment: Could you describe the large object more closely? Because this sounds like a bad design decision.

Comment: it an object containing 4000 word wich is selected after the heavy process

Answer (score 0):

After you've constructed your big object, serialize it to a file in the application's private data storage.

When your application starts, it should try to load the serialized object from the data file. If this fails, then it will need to construct the object again.

You can serialize it any way you want to. You just need to provide a method that can write the object to a stream, and another method that can initialize the object from that stream.